# What is the correct title for someone who gives podcasts?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word analogous to "blogger," but for someone who gives podcasts. "Podcaster" doesn't seem correct - the only thing I can think of is "host of a podcast." Is there a single word that better describes this profession?

Comment: I came here with this question, hoping for something more similar to a generic "author", "artist", or "performer" (where each of those has a connotation, but is general enough to apply to several different media each... "author" can write novels, poems, or news articles, "artist" can use paint, objects, music, etc, and "performer" can perform original things or other's works...) --- 

Maybe podcasting is just that unique of a medium, that no other previous word for talent quite fits...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*[Podcaster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/podcaster)* is listed in Merriam-Webster.

Comment: I guess I should know not to rely on MS Word spellchecker. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As the verb is *podcast*, who podcasts is a podcaster.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an alternative term to *podcaster*, [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podcast) notes:

> To avoid a term suggestive of "iPod", some use the term *netcast*
>   instead of podcast, such as the TWiT.tv podcaster Leo Laporte (though
>   the older term is also used in the broader sense of any
>   internet-delivered realtime media transmission).

Although *netcaster* sounds like someone who works on a fishing trawler.